# "daemon" command does not move to the background

Tags: linux, background-process, daemon

I'm in Linux, trying to use the `daemon` program in the apt package "`daemon`" to fork a background process to run as a daemon, but I'm having a problem: it does not appear to move to the background on its own. (I.e. the command prompt remains locked until I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.)

I need to make this command occur in a string of commands joined with `&&` (because this is part of a Docker `CMD`), so I can't simply press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> *or* terminate the line with a `&` to move the process to the background.

What can I do to make this process start in the background *AND* adjoin further commands to this one with a `&&`?

Comment: maybe `(cmd1 && cmd2 && ...) &` ? (so the subprocess set will be run in the background) OR a wrapper script? (same idea, basically) AND shouldn't a daemon process be started by the `init` system? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but I need two processes to run at the same time. That parenthetical would make a sequence of processes run in the background.

Comment: As for running the daemons with init, these two processes are meant to run in user space. I don't see how to do that with an `init.d` script. Do you know of a way?

Comment: Thanks again to @shelter; it looks like I can get the behaviour I want by putting the final `&` into parentheses: `(daemon -- myexecutable &) && (daemon -- anotherexecutable &) && ...`

Comment: you understand that `&&`ing the 2 daemons inside separate subshells (in the background) is only testing that the subshell was created and that the program was found, not that they finished sucessfully, which would be the normal reason to `&&` together 2 programs? Try `(no_suchprog & ) && (ls -l & )` to see what I mean. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, thank you. (I can't wait on the completion of the first daemon to get an exit code before starting the other daemon. They need to be concurrent.)

Comment: then why bother with the `&&`, you can do `daemon1 & daemon2 &` to get them both running in the background as soon as possible. Good luck.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize. Thanks!

Comment: That is not something you'll find on the `man` page. So live and learn! ;-) ..And to that point, think about how you could have written this Q to avoid so much back and forth and apply that learning  to the next Q you post ;-) . I like to think a good S.O. contains small sample inputs, expected output give those inputs, your code, and any error messages  (only some of that list are relevant to your current Q) as well as a brief "headline" description of the problem and your thoughts about how you want/need/intend to solve your problem and why you have chosen your current solution. Good luck!